# WYSIWYG jquery editor splitting into two text area

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am very surprised why it is happening, I am using jquery wysiwyg editor and it is splitting the text area into two. Any idea what may be causing this and how can I fix this ?

I am using ruby on rails and this is happening only in development, in production with precompile assets, this is not happening.

EDIT - I am using https://github.com/akzhan/jwysiwyg, here is the code on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8jQUn/ (the html part is generated through rails, like i said, it works in production but is splitting in development)

[image]

```
Thanks
```

Comment: can put your code in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Could you tell us what jquery editor are you using? Is it wymeditor?

Comment: impossible to troubleshoot without seeing this replicated in browser. Best bet is code duplication somewhere. Inspect browser source and see if multiple textareas created or dupication of script. Also inspect live html in browser console for clues

Comment: @mdvlpr - Done http://jsfiddle.net/8jQUn/

Comment: @Pigueiras - I am using https://github.com/akzhan/jwysiwyg

Answer (score 1):

for fix your CSS :

you must remove padding on `div.wysiwyg iframe`

```
div.wysiwyg iframe {
  clear: left;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0px 13px; /*REMOVE PADDING*/
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 97%; /* like 900px*/
}
```

and fix all widths to a unique value for your `div .wysiwyg` and inner `iframe`..

here is my edited : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8jQUn/1/)

Comment: Thanks, I removed precompiled assets and now it is working fine. I am still not sure what fixed it but things are working now. One question,  how to make element.style { min-height: 382px;width: 984px;} ? I can see the code in generated html but can't see it in the css file

Comment: I meant, this is the iframe code <iframe frameborder="0" style="min-height: 82px; width: 1084px;" id="page_body-wysiwyg-iframe"></iframe> and I want to increase the height through css, how to do it ?